# CRM 2011: How to Update record in a Create Plugin?

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2011

I'm having serious problems in how to update the record that has just been created with some additional data.

Case: I have an sms activity. On create an sms record. A plugin fires to actualy send the sms. A third party sms provider takes cares of the sending and returns a status string. Based on these string, a status for the sms must be updated.

Here's some of my code:

```csharp
public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
  IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)
  serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

  IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = 
    (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(
      typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
  IOrganizationService service = 
    serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);
  aContext orgContext = new aContext(service);

  Entity sms = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];
  /// logic goes here

  sms.StatusCode = new OptionSetValue(statuscode); //statuscode is integer
  service.Update(sms);
}
```

I got a error in the plugin everytime i execute the plugin. Can someone help and explain me what i'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want your plugin to be executed sync or async? What is your aContext? Is it the early-bound context? And do you use it?

Comment: Hi. it's sync. aContext is indeed my earlybound context. I sometimes use it in certain situations. I know i can use it for UpdateObject and SaveChanges methods but this is not working either in my situation.

Comment: I know there are issues if you try to update records retrieved with Linq from your context.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As your plugin is executed synchronously, it should be easy to update your entity if you use the *Pre-operation* stage of execution.

In this case, you can just do something like this:

```
Entity sms = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"]

// additional code to retrieve status

if(sms.Attributes.Contains("statuscode"))
    sms.Attributes["statuscode"] = new OptionSetValue(statuscode);
else
    sms.Attributes.add("statuscode", new OptionSetValue(statuscode));
```

In that way, you'll just add or update a key from the Attributes dictionnary, and it will be saved as if the value was coming directly from the form.

Comment: And what method should i use to update? I get the "sms With Id = 8d6d41ae-0d11-e111-b730-14feb5d96ef6 Does Not Exist" now when using service.update(sms);

Comment: Oooh, this is so good to know! i dont need any update method if you do it like this ^^ Thanks for this fantasitc answer!

Comment: You don't have to use any Update method. In Pre-operation, nothing has been saved in the database yet. But after your plugin is executed, everything you can find in the Attributes dictionary will be saved automatically.
So if you just add something in there, it will consider it like any other attributes, and save it in the same way.

Comment: Hi I am having same situation but its not running on 2016 pre-operation. I am getting following error. Changing state attributes is not allowed in create stage 20 plugins.