# Comparing, Adding, and Updating date field in an entity

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

Trying to compare an existing date from an entity with current date. If entity field (testfield) of entity (testentity) date is equal to OR after current date, then add 1 year to the date in the field.

**Issue** - For some reason, its reading all the dates and comparing as well but not updating it in the field. I have used post operation step on the entity.

**Update**: I added ServiceContext.UpdateObject(entity) and ServiceContext.SaveChanges(); to the code but now its giving me "The context is not currently tracking..." error.

**Any help would be deeply appreciated. Thanks!**

Please take a look at following code.

```
   public class PostUpdate: Plugin
{

    public PostUpdate()
        : base(typeof(PostUpdate))
    {
        base.RegisteredEvents.Add(new Tuple<int, string, string, Action<LocalPluginContext>>(40, "Update", "new_testentity", new Action<LocalPluginContext>(ExecutePostUpdate)));

      protected void ExecutePostupdate(LocalPluginContext localContext)
    {
        // get the plugin context 
        IPluginExecutionContext context = localContext.PluginExecutionContext;

        //Get the IOrganizationService
        IOrganizationService service = localContext.OrganizationService;

        //create the service context
        var ServiceContext = new OrganizationServiceContext(service);
        ITracingService tracingService = localContext.TracingService;

        // The InputParameters collection contains all the data passed in the message request.
        if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") &&
        context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
        {
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parmameters.
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];


            // Verify that the target entity represents an account.
            // If not, this plug-in was not registered correctly.
            if (entity.LogicalName != "new_testentity")
                return;

                    try
                    {
                        var k = entity["new_testfield"];
                        DateTime m = Convert.ToDateTime(k);

                        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;

                        int result = DateTime.Compare(m, d);

                        // compare the dates 
                        if (result <= 0)
                        {
                            try
                            {


                                entity["new_testfield"] = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
                                ServiceContext.UpdateObject(entity);
                            }
                        ServiceContext.SaveChanges();
                  //Adding this is giving me "The context is not currently tracking                    the 'new_testentity' entity."

                            }
                            catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                            {
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //<snippetFollowupPlugin3>
                    catch (FaultException<OrganizationServiceFault> ex)
                    {
                        throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException("An error occurred in the FollupupPlugin plug-in.", ex);
                    }
                    //</snippetFollowupPlugin3>

                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        tracingService.Trace("FollowupPlugin: {0}", ex.ToString());
                        throw;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You should register your plugin on the pre-operation step then simply add/change the appropriate value in the `InputParameter` PropertyBag. That way your changes are inline with the transaction and you don't need a separate update call.

Comment: Gregg, thanks a lot for your input. I registered the plugin in pre-operation step. 'if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && 
        context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity) 
        { 
            // Obtain the target entity from the input parmameters. 
            Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];' Should it be after this? and also should I add condition here? Sorry, I'm a little lost on how to do that. I would rreally appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you referring to comment by Renaud in this post? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8167571/crm-2011-how-to-update-record-in-a-create-plugin?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: @cashbowl: one way to find out - try it out! But that solution should work for you.

Comment: I did, Peter. But the field won't update even though the logic is right.

Comment: If your plugin is in the pre-operation stage, adding this in a branch that gets executed *will* work, assuming that "new_testfield" exists and is of type DateTime. You do not need ServiceContext.UpdateObject or ServiceContext.SaveChanges.     `var newValue = DateTime.Now.AddYears(1);
if(entity.Contains("new_testfield")){entity["new_testfield"] = newValue;}else{entity.Attributes.Add("new_testfield",newValue);}`

Comment: Gregg, sorry for taking so long to respond! That didn't work plus I tried a string value as well to see if the date is updating in the field and tried both pre and post operation but it still won't work.

Comment: int result = DateTime.Compare(m, d);
                    var newvalue = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1);
                    // compare the dates 
                    
                    if(entity.Contains("new_testfield"))
                    {


                        if (result <= 0)
                        {

                            entity["new_testfield"] = newvalue;

                        }
                        else
                            return;
                     }

Answer (score 0):

Try attaching your entity to the serviceContext.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.client.organizationservicecontext.attach.aspx